maui: navigate to another view from inside a view after a button click in mvvm
I am trying to open a new page from another viewmodel.
I am doing this:
My pages are registered:
builder.Services.AddSingleton<SettingsPageView, SettingsPageViewModel>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WifiPageView, WifiPageViewModel>();

In my SetttingsPageView i do this:
        <Button TextColor="Black" Command="{Binding ClickedWifiMenuCommand}"  Text="WIFI Menu"/>

And the command like this:
[RelayCommand]
public async void ClickedWifiMenu()
{
    Navigation.PushAsync(new WifiPageView());
}

But this is not working.
my Wifipage:
public partial class WifiPageViewModel: ObservableObject
{

    private readonly ILocalizationResourceManager _loc;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public WifiPageViewModel(ILocalizationResourceManager loc, ILogger logger)
    {

        _loc = loc;
        _logger = logger.ForContext<WifiPageViewModel>();

    }

code behind:
    public WifiPageView(WifiPageViewModel vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = vm;
    }

and my empty view:
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
...
             x:DataType="ViewModels:WifiPageViewModel">

    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Hi mom"/>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>

How can I open my view from my one view?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-8.0 If you are using shell, you use this.

You're already using dependency injection, and probably also Shell, so you could then also use Shell navigation. However, in MVVM, the ViewModel must not know anything about the View. Therefore, the navigation implementation should be hidden behind an interface. Unfortunately, Shell doesn't come with an interface for navigation, but you can simply create a proxy service with an interface and inject that into your ViewModel so that you can perform navigation in your command.

Thanks everybody; the quickest and in my eyes best solution was just to registre the view (somewhere before it is needed ofc):
    Routing.RegisterRoute("WifiPageViewModel", typeof(WifiPageView));

and then let the shell navigate:
 await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("WifiPageViewModel");


While this doesn't necessarily violate MVVM, this direct approach still comes with some issues. For example, you have a hard dependency on Shell in your ViewModel and you are using verbatim strings which are prone to typos and other issues related to naming.
